# py2Neo.ogm shortestPath search not turning up results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo, neo4j-ogm

I have implemented py2neo with ogm, however I cannot get the search functionality to work like it should. Below I have my cypher query (directly to the Neo4j db) with **'rpt_id'** and **'country_code'** as GraphObjects in the graph with those as the primary keys of the graph. The relationship between them is **PART_OF**.

```
MATCH (m:Column {name: '{rpt_id}'}), (n:Column {name:'{country_code}'}),
p = shortestPath((m)-[:PART_OF*..4]-(n)) 
RETURN p
```

I expect a response of the Tables (another ogm node) to go through to get to country_code, however, nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If nodes definitely exist that match **rpt_id** and **country_code** I expect the problem is the use of ticks around your parameters.  I would re-write the query as follows:

```
MATCH (m:Column {name: {rpt_id} }), (n:Column {name: {country_code} }), p = shortestPath((m)-[:PART_OF*..4]-(n)) 
RETURN p
```

Comment: That made the code run, thank you! The new output is completely jumbled because of py2neo v3 and I cannot figure out how to get names instead of random values: (b0c9a7a)-[:PART_OF]->(bda46cc)<-[:PART_OF]-(f94e681)-[:PART_OF]->(d59b20f)<-[:PART_OF]-(e0a6705)
If I run the code again, the variables change digits completely, how do I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you ask a new question with way more detail wrt to your new problem. I would counsel you to provide a minimal set of representative data so the problem can be easily recreated.